# Tap and hold Listbox Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

Does anybody know how can I add event whenever I press my `listbox` it will directly run my code. I need it to change my `listbox` selected item. This is my `xaml`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListNabi" SelectionChanged="ListNabi_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Tap="ListNabi_Tap" Hold="ListNabi_Hold">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="5,0,5,0">
                <!--<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="None"/>-->
                <Grid Width="480" Background="White">
                    <Image x:Name="listDaun" Source="/Images/Button/Button List.png"
                     Margin="0,5,5,5" Width="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Image>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="namaNabi"  TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                     Text="{Binding Name}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" 
                     FontSize="36" Foreground="#00ADCE" Margin="40,5,0,5"></TextBlock>
                    <Rectangle Margin="0,50,0,0" Height="2" Fill="#00ADCE" Width="480"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And in CS I did like this:

```
private void ListNabi_Hold(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    changeColor("#00ADCE", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", "/Images/Button/Button List1.png");
}

private void ListNabi_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    if (ListNabi.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        id = ListNabi.SelectedIndex;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("tes");
    changeColor("#00ADCE", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", "/Images/Button/Button List1.png");
}

private void ListNabi_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ListNabi.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        id = ListNabi.SelectedIndex;
        changeColor("#00ADCE", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", "/Images/Button/Button List1.png");
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/25_Nabi/DetailPage.xaml?id="
        + ListNabi.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
        ListNabi.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

But it will only run my code (in this context `changeColor()`) whenever I hold my `listbox` after some time or after I release my finger. Is there any event I can use to start run my code whenever my finger start touch?

Answer (score 0):

For that use the following events: `ManipulationStarted`, `ManipulationDelta` and `ManipulationCompleted`. You will get everything you need from positions to the number of different touch points.

You can do sophisticated things with it like dragging and pinching.

Comment: I need it just to change my listbox selected item color. But when I use manipulation... I can't change it. Any solution?